# filter a csv file by partial string matching for a column

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I have a big csv file(contains 21 column). The file contains last few days data of user. I want to filter this file based on column values. The column is "Logout Time". Column value is like "Mon Jun 15 11:12:12 EST 2015". I want to make a seperate csv file for those records whose "Logout Time" is "Mon Jun 15" irrespective of the time. 
I tried to do this using pandas.  To get those records I tried this:

```
df[df['Logout Time'].str.contains("Mon Jun 15")]
```

this gives me error as:

> ValueError : cannot index with vector containing NA / NaN values

I tried this one also:

```
df[df['Logout Time'].str.contains("Mon Jun 15") == True]
```

this doesnt filter the results. it gave me whole records of original csv.

Comment: Can you post the output from `df.info()` what is log out time? is a str or a datetime dtype? Your first attempt should have worked unless you had no matches, what does `df['Logout Time'].str.contains("Mon Jun 15")` show?

Comment: I see dtype for that column as object, neither str nor datetime.
df['Logout Time'].str.contains("Mon Jun 15") shows Value error
ValueError : cannot index with vector containing NA / NaN values

Comment: So does `df['Logout Time'].dropna().str.contains("Mon Jun 15")` return anything?

Comment: yes..It gives me the boolean output for the match (True/False)

Comment: So does `df[df['Logout Time'].dropna().str.contains("Mon Jun 15")]` work?

Comment: yes..that worked..but its a boolean output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that your data contains `NaN` values so you need to drop them using [`dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dropna.html#pandas.Series.dropna) first:

```
df[df['Logout Time'].dropna().str.contains("Mon Jun 15")]
```

so the above should work.